IIS Express: configure domain to be used for Windows authentication
When running an ASP.NET project that uses Windows Authentication in VS using IIS Express on a computer joined to domain C.B.A, the authentication works and local groups of C.B.A that the user is part of are found in the WindowsPrincipal claims.
However, when running this exact project on a computer that is joined to domain B.A, it stops working. Users are no longer able to be authenticated.
My question is, is it possible to configure IIS Express to use domain C.B.A for Windows Authentication even though the computer that IIS Express is running on is joined on domain B.A? Will this even solve this issue?
I tried looking up ways to configure IIS Express using the web.config on MSDN and Stack Overflow, without any results.

Your domain administrators should be the right resources to guide you through how Windows authentication works internally. IIS/IIS Express does not perform authentication itself, but passes on that to Windows/DC. Thus, the primary DC of the actual machine handles the authentication. And if Windows authentication failed for some reasons, domain administrators should troubleshoot for you.

Thanks for your comment. I went to them before asking here, and they say I should be configurable in the web.config and therefore not a problem on their side. I will go speak with them again.
